# How to add image with url when converting html to pdf in angular 10?

Tags: javascript, angular, html-to-pdf

I did

```
<img height="auto" width="230"[src]="imageUrl" />
```

It shows error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Invalid image: File
> 'http:test.png' not found in virtual file system Images dictionary
> should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)

Here is js code

```
public downloadAsPDF():void {

    const doc = new jsPDF();
    const pdfTable = this.pdfTable.nativeElement;
    let html = htmlToPdfmake(pdfTable.innerHTML);

    const documentDefinition = { content: html };
    pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).open();
  }
```

- I changed the image url in error and replaced it with '`http:test.png`' while posting question here.

Comment: Try providing base64 string as image URL instead of a remote URL path.